# How do I populate a spinner from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner, android-spinner

My requirement is too populate a spinner from another actvity.

The Main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

The other activity:

```
public class TravellerData extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.array.the_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

When the main activity is started, I require the spinner to be populated from the other activity. Will I have to use an intent? Is there any way to simply start the activity.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you asking exactly? the spinner will be automatically created with your `TravellerData` activity. do you need information on how to start this activity from your `Main` activity?

Comment: Didn't get you why you are populating spinner from another activity and what does that mean?

Comment: Guys, sorry if I didn't phrase my question properly!

@andr, that's just what I need. How do I simply start the Activity from Main. TravellerData has no UI/xml. It is simply meant to populate the spinner.

Comment: @chrish, I have a requirement that requires me to populate the spinner from another class/activity.

Comment: what do you mean by "populate"? you *can't* start an activity without a content view! that's the whole purpose of activity.

Comment: An activity must have an UI/XMl. I think you misunderstood the concept of activty.

Comment: @andr, by populate I mean load values into. I have a string array 'the_array' defined under res/values/strings.xml the items of which should be loaded into the spinner.

Comment: @psykhi, I guess so. So in that case, can I simply define TravellerData as a class and somehow instantiate the class to load the values into the spinner?

Comment: Yes, or just paste its code in a function, I don't really see why you couldn't.